# Using prototype to extend controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
TestController = function ($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.test = this;
  $scope.name = 'World';
    this.init();
    $interval(function () {
        //Added this because we shouldn't update until we either get the user data or that request fails
        $scope.test.init();
    }, 500);
};
TestController.prototype.init = function () {
    console.log("Test this thing");
};
app.controller('MainCtrl', TestController);
```

This works great but now I need to include the init function in another controller so I want both to inherit from a common prototype. However, when I try [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/VeGbhCqKw9RtLRxCi78j?p=preview) plunker it doesn't seem to work.

What is the proper way to handle this sort of thing in JS?

Comment: in plunker you have `function TimeBox` but in prototype try assign `TestController.prototype = new Test()`

Comment: Thanks updated still has the same issue

Comment: all work if you define all function in `app.js` file, or add reference to `test.js` in `index.html`

Comment: I don't want all my JS in one file. That seems like maintenance hell

Comment: if you want use code from `test.js` in page `index.html` - you need add reference to this script file like `<script src="test.js"></script>` :-)

Comment: Updated still no worky

Comment: Just include `test.js` before `app.js` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is TypeScript example http://plnkr.co/edit/HOeJ7nkkp2qRl53zEvVj?p=preview

TypeScript:

```
class Controller {
  static $inject = ['$scope']; // deps

  constructor($scope) {
    $scope.vm = this;
  }

  value(): string {
    return '123';
  }
}

class NewController extends Controller {
  constructor($scope) {
    super($scope);
  }

  value(): string {
    return super.value() + '456';
  }
}

declare var angular: any;
angular.module('my', []).controller('controller', NewController);
```

In JavaScript it looks like:

```
//Compiled TypeScript

var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
}

var Controller = (function () {
    function Controller($scope) {
        $scope.vm = this;
    }
    Controller.$inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];
    Controller.prototype.value = function () {
        return '123';
    };
    return Controller;
})();

var NewController = (function (_super) {
    __extends(NewController, _super);
    function NewController($scope) {
        _super.call(this, $scope);
    }
    NewController.prototype.value = function () {
        return _super.prototype.value.call(this) + '456';
    };
    return NewController;
})(Controller);

angular.module('my', []).controller('controller', NewController);
```

If you need OOP in JavaScript use smth like http://prototypejs.org/

Comment: I will take a look at what you have posted and check after I get a chance to digest thanks!